# Mean of List Containing Strings Error in NetLogo

Tags: string, mean, netlogo

I am having an issue with calculating the mean of a list of numbers and strings in netlogo. The user manual states that mean takes the average of a list while ignoring non-numeric values, but it errors out when there is a non-numeric value in my list. I can remove the strings from my lists, but it would be tedious as I have 10 lists with the first two values being strings describing the list contents (I would plan to use the but-first command twice to get rid of the strings).

The error specifically says : "Can't find the mean of a list that contains non-numbers : Walk Distance is a string."

Is there a different way to calculate this mean so that the strings are ignored like I think it reads in the manual? Or am I misunderstanding the manual?

Sample code if you need it:

```
output-type "Avg Walking Distance Uninformed (orange) " output-print mean OrangeWalk
output-type "Avg Cruise Distance Uninformed (orange) " output-print mean OrangeCruise
```

Comment: I opened https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/637 on the mismatch between the doc and the behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter using `is-number?`.  E.g., `mean filter [is-number? ?] [1 "22" 3]` or just `mean filter is-number? [1 "22" 3]`.

Ah, I just looked up the docs for `filter` and this is implicitly suggested by the first example there:
http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#filter